# Not the right frame size when trying to set collection view cell layout in delegate

Tags: ios, swift

Every first cell should be the width of the collection view and the next 2 should be half of its size.

It doesn't really matter because the problem is that collectionView.frame.width returns a wrong value.

If I check view.frame on the iPhone 5, it is the one that iPhone 6 should have:

```
  ▿ size : (375.0, 667.0)
    - width : 375.0
    - height : 667.0
```

On iPhone 5, the width should be 320 and the height 568.

I also tried to print the view's width in the viewDidLayoutSubviews, but with the same result.

On iPhone 6, everything is working fine. The problem is also happening on iPhone 6+.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 390)
        }

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 2 - 4,  height: 335)
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help but when I have been facing these issues, it usually helps to look at the storyboard for different phone sizes (compact, regular etc) just to see what it looks like and try to figure out where the disconnect happens between the collectionView and its viewLayout

Comment: is your storyboard setup with iPhone 6 as default? Sometimes you get wrong/default storyboard values for the frames because at the time you are accessing it, not all the layouting cycles are complete. Are you manually calling any of the collectionView delegate methods? Also, how are your constraints for the collectionView in the storyboard? Are you sure they are setup correctly?